# Twitter bot that replies to all the tweets of my friend. Python

Tags: python, twitter, bots

Hello I am searching how to create a Twitter bot that replies to all the tweets of a specific user in Python.
I already created a developer's account and I am a beginner in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, visit https://dev.twitter.com, and create a new application.
[image]
[image]

head your venv or anaconda and execute

```
pip install tweepy
```

Now, in your development directory, create a file, keys.py, and add the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#keys.py
#visit https://dev.twitter.com to create an application and get your keys
keys = dict(
    consumer_key =          'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    consumer_secret =       'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    access_token =          'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    access_token_secret =   'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
)
```

Replace the ‘x’ fields with your keys and tokens from your newly created Twitter application

create a file, replybot.py, in the same directory as keys.py, and add the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tweepy
#from our keys module (keys.py), import the keys dictionary
from keys import keys

CONSUMER_KEY = keys['consumer_key']
CONSUMER_SECRET = keys['consumer_secret']
ACCESS_TOKEN = keys['access_token']
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = keys['access_token_secret']

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

twts = api.search(q="Hello World!")

#list of specific strings we want to check for in Tweets
t = ['Hello world!',
    'Hello World!',
    'Hello World!!!',
    'Hello world!!!',
    'Hello, world!',
    'Hello, World!']

for s in twt:
    for i in t:
        if i == s.text:
            sn = s.user.screen_name
            m = "@%s Hello!" % (sn)
            s = api.update_status(m, s.id)
```

Check if your API is working . sleep is you ensure you are not asked to validate you are a bot python <program.py> .txt

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tweepy, time, sys

argfile = str(sys.argv[1])

#enter the corresponding information from your Twitter application:
CONSUMER_KEY = '1234abcd...'#keep the quotes, replace this with your consumer key
CONSUMER_SECRET = '1234abcd...'#keep the quotes, replace this with your consumer secret key
ACCESS_KEY = '1234abcd...'#keep the quotes, replace this with your access token
ACCESS_SECRET = '1234abcd...'#keep the quotes, replace this with your access token secret
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

filename=open(argfile,'r')
f=filename.readlines()
filename.close()

for line in f:
    api.update_status(line)
    time.sleep(900)#Tweet every 15 minutes
```

To reply to specific twitter user

```
toReply = "someonesTwitterName" #user to get most recent tweet
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#get the most recent tweet from the user
tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = toReply, count=1)

for tweet in tweets:
    api.update_status("@" + toReply + " This is what I'm replying with", in_reply_to_status_id = tweet.id)
```

you can code whatever logic you want